# MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable is not set for mariadb container if I using .env file in swarm

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-swarm

When I try to set up a cluster with docker swarm I receive this error:

```
$ docker logs 6ea0f7290cb0  
2020-11-30 10:46:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
2020-11-30 10:46:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-11-30 10:46:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
2020-11-30 10:46:08+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
        You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

What is weird because if I use the docker-compose tool, everything works well.

To replicate this problem follow the steps below.

Create a `.env` file:

```
DB_NAME=nest
DB_USERNAME=nest
DB_PASSWORD=nest
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=nest
```

Create a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
```

If I use the command `docker-compose up -d`, I can check that everything works well with the `docker-compose ps` command:

```
$ docker-compose ps
    Name                  Command             State    Ports  
--------------------------------------------------------------
db-debug_db_1   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      3306/tcp
```

If I use the command `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml db`, I can check that the database is not started with the command `docker service ls`:

```
$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
ux1p4k6vwiyh        db_db               replicated          0/1                 mariadb:latest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker-compose` and `docker stack deploy` have a number of differences in how they parse the compose.yml file. One of them being that the latter does not automatically process a .env files. ([reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file))
As such you need to explicitly reference it:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    env_file: .env
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Portainer agent for deployment on my Swarm cluster and the .env file method doesn't works there.
https://www.portainer.io/blog/using-env-files-in-stacks-with-portainer. Seems like they have some bug in their app.
https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/6701
unable to use this method therefore.

Comment: How does this provide an answer to the question?